# React-i18next does not load translations on page reload

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

I am using react-I18next in my nextjs application. I don't want to use next-I18next because I tried to use it but couldn't make it work. But react-i18next is working in my application for now and I am able to change language from english to german and back. However if I reload the page I get this error.

> TypeError: i18n.changeLanguage is not a function

What could be the possibel cause of this error and how can I fix it?
P.S In my app.ts file I am not using Suspense because it gives me this error

> ReactDOMServer does not yet support Suspense.

Here is my i18.ts file

```
/* eslint-disable no-duplicate-imports */
import i18n from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import loginDE from '../../public/locales/de/loginDE.json';
import loginEN from '../../public/locales/en/loginEN.json';

// the translations
// (tip move them in a JSON file and import them)
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: loginEN,
  },
  de: {
    translation: loginDE,
  },
};

void i18n
  .use(backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
    resources,
    lng: 'en',
    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome
    react: {
      useSuspense: true,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need to create a reproducible example...
btw. next-i18next is especially designed for next.js apps, so I would suggest you're try again with it...
fyi: there is an example using custom i18next backends here: https://github.com/locize/next-i18next-locize

Answer (score 0):

1. > ReactDOMServer does not yet support Suspense.

Change your **useSuspense** value like that:

```
react: { useSuspense: false },
```

2. > TypeError: i18n.changeLanguage is not a function

Make sure you wrapped a component with **I18nextProvider**